# Removing only my files in Unix

Tags: unix

I need to rm files from a unix directory that only belong to my id. I tried building this command, but to no avail:

```
ls -la | grep 'myid' | awk ' { print $9 } ' | rm
```

My result: Usage: rm [-firRe] [--] File...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You were really close.  Try:

```
rm `ls -la | grep 'myid' | awk ' { print $9 } '`
```

Note that those are backticks, not single quotes surrounding the first three segments from your original pipeline.  Also for me the filename column was $8, but if $9 is the right column for you, then that should do it.

Comment: Thank you very much for the input. Worked great. It is less typing than the other answers, but I do appreciate those as well.

Comment: this fails for me because my prompt is colored: rm: cannot remove `\033[0m.X1-lock\033[0m': No such file or directory -- the \033[0m is coming in from an environment variable (prompt)

Comment: In order to a directory that is inside, you can use the -r option. (rm -r `ls -la | grep 'myid' | awk ' { print $9 } '`)

Answer (score 16):

```
find . -user myuser -print0 |xargs -0 rm
```

Put your own userid (or maybe user number) in for "myuser".

Answer (score 13):

`rm` doesn't read from stdin.

```
find -user $(whoami) -delete
```

Please always test without the delete first.

Comment: Note, add -type f if you only want to delete files.

Comment: Also possibly a -maxdepth 1 to only work in the current directory.

Comment: This is the most concise, but note that you have to put the directory in the command before the -user option, e.g. 'find . -user $(whoami) -delete'

Comment: You don't in GNU find.  You may be right that the standard (http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/find.html) requires it, though.

Comment: ah, good to know. In that case nevermind :-)

Answer (score 5):

Try with `find` where you can search for files belonging to a user and then delete them:

```
find . -user *username* -delete
```

More info: `man find`

Answer (score 3):

rm does not accept a list of files to delete on the stdin (which is what you are doing by passing it through the pipe.

Try this

```
find . -type f -user username -exec rm -f {} \;
```

Answer (score 3):

Delete files of `user_name` from folder `/tmp` (you can replace this with your folder) older than 60 days - you ca use any date here but make sure you keep evidence in a `deleted.txt` file in `user_name` home folder:

```
find /tmp -user user_name -mtime +60 -exec rm -rfv {} \; >> /home/user_name/deleted.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use find:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -user myid -print0 | xargs -0 rm -f
```

Drop the -maxdepth 1 if you want it to handle subdirectories as well.